# How to solve $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This is a first order multi-dimensional PDEs. The question requires to solve in form $f(x, y, t)$ where $f(x, y, t=0)$ is known.

I know how to solve when there is only 2 terms (i.e. no "$y$" term): if set $g(x) = f(x, t = 0)$ is provided, then $f(x, t)=g(x - t)$. However, how to extend this result to this situation? Many thanks!

Comment: A function of 3 variables, the divergence is equal to zero.  Perhaps you have seen that type or problem before?

Comment: You format your title in a good way. You might want to LaTeX your question also.

Comment: I just know $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$ with method mentioned in the question, but how about the 2-dimensional case? Quite confused...

Comment: Format improved now :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dt}{ds}=1$ , letting $t(0)=0$ , we have $t=s$

$\dfrac{dx}{ds}=1$ , letting $x(0)=x_0$ , we have $x=s+x_0=t+x_0$

$\dfrac{dy}{ds}=1$ , letting $y(0)=y_0$ , we have $y=s+y_0=t+y_0$

$\dfrac{df}{ds}=0$ , letting $f(0)=F(x_0,y_0)$ , we have $f(x,y,t)=F(x_0,y_0)=F(x-t,y-t)$

Comment: Still a bit confused in the last line. Do you mean $f(0)=F(x_0, y_0) = f(x, y, 0)$?

Comment: My initial condition is  $f(x,y,t=0)=e^{(−100[(x−0.5)^2+(y−0.5)^2])}$. Does that mean $f(x, y, t)=e^{(−100[(x−0.5-t)^2+(y−0.5-t)^2])}$?